# How to combine onTap with Gestures?

Tags: android, gestures

It would have been nice to see an example of how to combine onTap with Gestures and how to determine the tap position in a zoomed image. (I have used each of them separately, but I suspect some interference here, and I am not sure what kind of x-y coordinates are given for a scaled image.  I need the tap-position in the image)